# swift: JSON not working correctlly after changing device language

Tags: json, swift, youtube

I made JSON request to get goole YouTube search suggestions, if I pass an Arabic lettrs as a search keyword it works fine if the device language is English, but if I change it to Arabic I got this message:

> JSON could not be serialized because of error:
>   The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

The code:

```
        //Prepare Keyword string
    searchKeyword = (searchKeyword as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")

    //Prepare url string
    var str: String = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?ds=yt&client=firefox&hjson=t&q='\(searchKeyword)'"
    str = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

    //Getting the data
    Alamofire.request(str).responseJSON { (response) in
        //If error
        if let error = response.error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        //If successed
        if let jsonArray = response.result.value as? NSArray {
            //Use the data
        }
    }
```

Remark:
when the device is in English interface I got Content-Type = charset=ISO-8859-1 in JSON response description
but when the device is in Arabic interface Content-Type = charset=windows-1256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line and the problem is resolved!!

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar", "en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
```